Visual Studio / nmake: how can I set build log verbosity and log file?
I have to build a C++ project from the command line using the nmake tool (part of Visual Studio), and I am interested in the build logs.
Looking at Microsoft online documentation I did not find much.
I tried with the /X option with no success.
All I could get so far is to redirect nmake's output on file with:
nmake >> output.log

Is there a way to get more detailed information than what provided by the default?

Does /D help? And there is a suggestion here: Seeing what commands nmake is issuing.
